# How to replace IN clause with JOIN in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have following query .

```
select entity_id ,parent_id,name as label , url_key as name from magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 where entity_id IN(
SELECT distinct T1.parent_id
FROM magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 T1 
INNER JOIN magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 as T2 ON 
           T1.entity_id = T2.parent_id
RIGHT JOIN sohyper_region_activity as T3 on 
           T2.entity_id = T3.activity_id)
```

The above query decreases the performance because of IN clause . Can anyone tell me how to replace IN clause with JOIN in this query ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT Tab1.entity_id ,Tab1.parent_id,Tab1.name As Label , Tab1.url_key As Name 
FROM magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 Tab1 JOIN
(
SELECT distinct T1.parent_id
FROM magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 T1 
INNER JOIN magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 as T2 ON 
           T1.entity_id = T2.parent_id
RIGHT JOIN sohyper_region_activity as T3 on 
           T2.entity_id = T3.activity_id
) Tab2 ON Tab1.entity_id = Tab2.parent_id
```

Answer (score 18):

In general

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM ...)
```

can be converted to:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM ...) t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, obviously!

```
WITH (
SELECT distinct T1.parent_id
FROM magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 T1 
INNER JOIN magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 as T2 ON 
           T1.entity_id = T2.parent_id
RIGHT JOIN sohyper_region_activity as T3 on 
           T2.entity_id = T3.activity_id)
) T0
select entity_id ,parent_id,name as label , url_key as name from 
magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 T1 
INNER JOIN magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1 as T2 ON 
           T1.entity_id = T2.parent_id
RIGHT JOIN sohyper_region_activity as T3 on 
           T2.entity_id = T3.activity_id
INNER JOIN T0
ON T0.entity_id = magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.entity_id
```